# converting the OPEN function with an Err specifiers in fortran into fopen function in PHP

Tags: php, fopen, goto, fortran90

I need to find an equivalent expression for a fortran line in php:
fortran code:

```
10    OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE='TEST.OUT',STATUS='NEW', ERR=9001)
      GOTO 11
9001  OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE='TEST.OUT')
      CLOSE(10,STATUS='DELETE')
      OPEN(UNIT=2,FILE='fort2')
      CLOSE(2,STATUS='DELETE')
      GOTO 10
11    OPEN(UNIT=7,FILE='TEST.SUM',STATUS='NEW')
```

I would like to convert this code into a php code. I would like to use fopen function but I do not know how to aks it to jump to line 9001 to delete old files fisrt if there is any old file.
Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you just describe in English what this code is supposed to do? You want to fopen a file, but if it already exists, you want to remove the old file, then fopen a new one?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what that Fortran code is doing exactly, but it sounds like you want this:

```
$fh = fopen('TEST.OUT', 'w');
```

Note the description of the `'w'` mode:

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Otherwise possibly:

```
do {
    $fh = @fopen('TEST.OUT', 'x');
    if (!$fh) {
        unlink('TEST.OUT');
        unlink('fort2');
    }
} while (!$fh);
```

> `'x'`: Create and open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file. If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

You should be careful not to get into an infinite loop there though.

You can also do those checks yourself:

```
if (file_exists('TEST.OUT')) {
    unlink('TEST.OUT');
    unlink('fort2');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot deceze! The do- while loop exatly does what the fortran code does.